# RegEx - to be used in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have 3 current URLs that all should redirect to the same new URL:

Current:

../en/nike-air-max
../en/products/nike-air-max
../en/brands/nike

Should all redirect to:

../en/brand/nike

Is the RegEx below safe to be used for the URLs to be redirected in htaccess?

../(en|(en/(products|brands)))/nike.*

I'm not all too familiar with RegEx, please correct me if you think this can be done easier or cleaner or more correct (I'm not a developer).

Thank you!

Comment: URLs don't start with `../` Provide full URLs as you see in your browser and how it should be redirected?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 "(/en/nike-air-max|/en/products/nike-air-max|/en/brands/nike)" "/en/brand/nike"
```